# How do I test for the result of a regular expression in a switch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, switch-statement

I was wondering why the result of my regular expression wasn't going to the case I wanted to go through.

```
var r = "This is a test.";
var ex = /a/g;
var l = ex.exec(r);

alert(l);

switch (l)
{
    case "a":
      alert("good");
      break;

    default:
      alert("error");
}
```

If you run this, you can see that "l" does in fact does equal "a" which then should trigger the case function.  If anyone knows why it isn't, please help.  Thank you

Comment: Because `l` is `["a", index: 8, input: "This is a test.", groups: undefined]`. When you `alert` it, `l` is converted to string using `toString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test against `l[0]` instead to get the matched substring:

```js
var r = "This is a test.";
var ex = /a/g;
var l = ex.exec(r);

switch (l[0])
{
    case "a":
      alert("good");
      break;

    default:
      alert("error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions you have matches, To check the matches that your regex is generating use console.log, the devtool built-in debugger or pages like https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

@LoganMacMonkey, the type return by  **var l = ex.exec(r);** is array. Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) and you try to compare array with string using switch case structure. Due to this reason your code is not working

To resolve it Convert

```
 switch (l)
```

To the,

```
 switch(l.toString())
```

Hope it you are looking for the same!! :)